# Django　データベースで外部参照をつなげる方法

Tags: python, python3, django

以下のようにDjangoのアプリ内models.py,views.pyを記述しました。
Parsonに、複数のテーブルが外部参照（ForeignKey）されているものとします。
Parson含め、どれかのテーブルのカラムでfilterして、InnarJoinで一括でデータを取り出したいのですが、どういう構文にすればよいのかが分かりません。

models.py

```
from django.db import models
import json

class Parson(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='name',max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        set_dict = {
            'name':self.name,
        }
        return json.dumps(set_dict)

class ParsonInfo(models.Model):
    gender = models.CharField(verbose_name='gender',max_length=10)
    age = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='age')
    key = models.ForeignKey(Parson,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='parson_key')

    def __str__(self):
        set_dict = {
            'gender':self.gender,
            'age':self.age,
        }
        return json.dumps(set_dict)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Parson, ParsonInfo

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    parson = Parson.objects.filter(ParsonInfo__gender="男性").all()

    params = {
        'parson':parson,
    }
    return render(request,'app/index.html',params)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決したので回答します。

Djangoでは、InnerJoinをデフォルトで発行しているようです。

上記の例では、gender="男性"で絞り込みたい場合には、参照側を使って、

```
    parson = ParsonInfo.objects.filter(gender="男性").all()
    for obj in parson:
        print(obj.key.name,obj.age,obj.gender)
```

Index.htmlでの取り出しでも同じように.で接続すればよいようです。

Comment: はい。ただしその方法だとN+1が発生するのでお気を付けください。
parson = ParsonInfo.objects.filter(gender="男性").select_related("key").all()
のように対策すると良いと思います。